# How to move routing to separate file in ASP.NET v6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

In ASP.NET for .NET 6, you can add routing in Program.cs like `app.MapGet("/name", YourDelegate)`. Is it possible to move it to separate file and include to Program.cs?

Comment: Move it anywhere you like, pass `app` to that method?

Comment: @Charles Mager, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to program

```
Apis.Apis.GetApis(app);

app.Run();
```

and create a separate file including class Apis  , with APIs like this for example

```
namespace Apis
{
    public static partial class Apis
    {
        public static void GetApis(WebApplication app)
        {
     
            app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

            app.MapGet("/api/clients", () => new Client()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Client 1"
            });
            app.MapGet("/api/clients/{id:int}", (int id) => new Client()
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = "Client " + id
            });
        }
    }

   public  class Client
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

you can create as many files as you need